# C# Assigning a variable pointing to a reference type to another variable, what is stored in the latter variable?

Tags: c#, types, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I m trying to understand what happens when assigning a variable `a` which already stores a reference to an object instance `MyClass` to a new variable `b`.
E.g.

```
    var a = new MyClass("some name"); 
    //assume instance has an address 1, var a's address is 2 and the value is the address of object instance(1). 
    var b = a;
```

I thought the value stored in `b` would be the address of `a` which is 2, but it seems when I output the value of `b` the result is actually 1.
e.g.

```
    setName(ref a, "NEW NAME");
    public void setName (ref MyClass instance, string name)
    {
        instance = new MyClass(name)
    }
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
```

The output is

```
NEW NAME   //a.Name
some name  //b.Name
```

I was expecting both variables' names to change since I thought `b` is storing a pointer to `a`. but it seems `b` is storing the value of `a` instead of its address?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(The [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65434230/revisions) tried to explain by using the terminology of pointers, however, this seems to have overly complicated things)</sub>

Calling `setName(ref a, "NEW NAME")` is functionally equivalent to inlining the body of `setName()` with `instance` replaced by `a`:

```cs
var a = new MyClass("some name"); 
var b = a;
a = new MyClass("NEW NAME");
Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
```

It is clear now that the value of `b.Name` has no reason to change in this scenario. The addition of the function `setName()` where `a` is passed by reference makes no difference to the outcome of `b`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So... when assigning `a` to `b`, we are assigning the value of `a` to `b` instead of `a`'s memory location/reference? I mean the result suggested as much but I was not able to find why this behavior is happening, since I assume `a` is still a variable of the reference type. Could be my carelessness when reading the documentation.

Comment: @ChenL no you're not copying the data, you're copying the address when you assign `a` to `b`.

Comment: If by "copying address" u mean copying `a`'s address to `b`'s value, then should a change to the value of `a` change the value of `b` as well since `b` is storing the address of `a`? Sorry, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @ChenL I understand that it's confusing. You have to think of the addresses themselves as values in their own right. Once you accept that, then it's easier to understand why `b`'s address doesn't change while `a`'s does.

Comment: @ChenL `b`'s address is a _copy_ of `a`'s original address. When you pass `a` by reference, only the value of `a`'s address is subject to change. Why would there be an exception? There's still an active reference to the data, it can't be marked for GC.

Comment: Ohhhh, so `b` shares the same memory address as `a`'s original address. Make sense now. I thought `b` would have a different memory address and just saves the memory address of `a`, thank you @Patrick Roberts.

Comment: the original "pointer" answer was easier for me to understand :)